What does it actually mean algorithm true for component in AntDesign5?
What difference between algorithm "false" and "true" in AntDesign? It doesnt affect for anymore
You can switch the algorithm control for component in https://ant.design/theme-editor and nothing will happen.
import React from 'react';
import { Button, ConfigProvider, Input, Space, theme } from 'antd';

const App: React.FC = () => (
    <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
            "token": {
                "controlHeight": 20
            },
            "components": {
                "Input": {
                    "controlHeight": 60,
                    // What actually it means?
                    "algorithm": true
                }
            }
        }}
    >
        <Space>
            <Input placeholder="Please Input" />
            <Button type="primary">Submit</Button>
        </Space>
    </ConfigProvider>
);

export default App;

